# How will I create a Dropdown list in asp.net mvc 5 with hard-coded string values in it...?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wan't to enter the address details in a particular application. I need to get the name of city , state and the country in drop-down.How can I achieve it ? Is there any other way to achieve the same without using Javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

I like using Enumerations personally. MVC 5 has built in support for Enum to drop down lists, use the EnumDropDownListsFor helper class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.enumdropdownlistfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Your enumeration:

```
public enum country
{
  usa
  others
}
```

Inside your view:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.country,"Select a Country",null)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add items and their values as code below.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="us">United State America</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="ca">Canada</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```